# Mongodb ObjectID MachineID part seems to differ for requests coming from same machine

Tags: mongodb

I have encountered the issue of generating MongoDB requests (using node.js and the native driver or mongoose) always from same machine, but the generated ObjectIDs have a different "machine part" while I would expect them to match.
I searched the Q&A and found the below description:

"The next three bytes of an ObjectId are a unique identifier of the machine on which it was generated. This is usually a hash of the machine’s hostname. By including these bytes, it is guranteed that different machines will not generate colliding ObjectIds."

I should assume that this hash should always produce same result if the origin machine is the same - am I getting something wrong? thanks in advance.

Giorgos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not produce the same result always. A reboot of the machine or even a request made few hours later produces different machine part.